# How to call a function in a case statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello I am new at this and I Would like to call the function menu in the other case statement so that when i press 1 it directly goes to the case which is labelled groceries.Hopefully I have explained myself thoroughly.

```
static void menu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Select a category to view");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("1.Groceries");
    Console.WriteLine("2.Electronics & Appliances");
    Console.WriteLine("3.Exit");
    Console.ReadKey();

    int response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (response)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("...........Groceries...............");
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("..............Electronics & Appliances............");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("...........Exit...............");
            break;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    menu();

    Console.WriteLine(@" Choose items being purchased from Groceries /n      
          1:stove = 3000 \n 2: potcollection = 2000 \n
          3:lemonsqeezer = 1000 \n 4:oven = 10000 \n 5:blender = 6000");
    double stove = 3000;
    double lemonsqeezer = 1000;
    double oven = 10000;
    double blender = 6000;
    double potcollection = 2000;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number from the above groceries list");

    int response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (response == 1)
        switch (response)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("The total is{0}",);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}",);
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: The code that you have above `Main()` needs to be inside a method. I don't see that you have that. Is that just a copy and paste mistake? Also, are you asking how to find out what the result of the menu is?

Comment: please align the contents properly, The code above the main is a part of which function? In the given snippet there are two switch cases, what is the difficulty that you are facing currently. `In short your question is not clear enough`

Comment: your question (how to call a function in a switch statement) doesn't make sense in the context here.  you only have one function in this code, and you are already *inside* that function when you are in the switch statement.  if you want to call the other code that is here, you need to create another function for it, and calling it would be the same inside the switch as calling it from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified you code:

```
static void menu()
{
    double[] groceries = new double[] { 3000, 1000, 10000, 6000, 2000 }; // By creating an array, you can easily get the price of an item by the index.
    // double[] groceries = new double[] { stove, lemonsqeezer, oven, blender, potcollection };

    // double[] electronics_and_appliances = new double[] { ... };

    Console.WriteLine("Select a category to view");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("1.Groceries");
    Console.WriteLine("2.Electronics & Appliances");
    Console.WriteLine("3.Exit");

    int response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (response)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("...........Groceries...............");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(@" Choose items being purchased from Groceries /n      
               1:stove = 3000 \n 2: potcollection = 2000 \n
               3:lemonsqeezer = 1000 \n 4:oven = 10000 \n 5:blender = 6000");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number from the above groceries list");

            // This prevents IndexOutOfRangeException.
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}", groceries[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1]); // Minus one becuase index's start from 0.
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That item doesn't exist");
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("..............Electronics & Appliances............");
            /*

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(@"Choose items being purchased from Electronics & Appliances/n ...");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number from the above Electronics & Appliances list");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}", electronics_and_appliances[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1]);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That item doesn't exist");
            }

            */
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("...........Exit...............");
            break;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    menu();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You always process option `1`, because you have an `if` statement wrapping your `switch`.

```
if (response == 1) // no other response other than 1 will get processed.
    switch (response)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("The total is{0}",);
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}",);
            break;
    }
}
```

Remove the `if` and the other `case` statements will get executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're already doing it.

```
switch (response)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("...........Groceries...............");
```

You're calling `Console.WriteLine` from your `case`. You can call another method or function the same way.

Comment: The actual issue is that he's wrapped the `switch` inside an `if` statement that causes `response == 1` to be the only condition allowed.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. I guess I'm just being very literal. I answered the literal question, but that's not really what he's asking.